# Database Design of Bugtracking software

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing my database for a bugtracking software in which there are some users and other entities. I don't know how to manage them. Please kindly help me out. There are many to many relations in them like one tester can work on many projects and one project can have many testcases, so the question is how I manage the tables and their entities so that I can retrieve data about any bug user or project with one query only. I am working with SQL Server 2012.

These are the entities:

1. Manager (create project and users(coders/testers))
2. Coder (create bugs)
3. Tester (create test cases)
4. projects
5. Bugs
6. TestCases

Comment: Should i make one table of users or should i make seprate tables of manager, coder and tester

Comment: Your original question is entirely too broad. But on the topic of separate tables it depends. Do you store different data for each type of user? I suspect probably not. To me those sound like roles and a person would be assigned to a role. Storing them in different tables causes challenges if a person needs to change or if a person can have multiple roles.

Comment: you could make one user table with a column indicating the user type (coder/tester/manager).  You could also include a column to hold the primary key of the user's manager if that is relevant in your application

Comment: Thank you so much @SeanLange but if i store all the users in one table then how can i fetch information about the infor related to them like bugs are related to coders only and testcases are related to testers only

Comment: By using the foreign keys? What happens when a person is a coder and a tester? Are you going to store them in both tables? That is not a good way to handle these things. You really need to spend some time reading about how relational data works before you start designing databases. Here is an awesome series of articles on getting started with designing databases. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72400/